DialogFragment の onCreateView() をオーバーライドし、ダイアログのレイアウトを一部だけ変えたい
Android のアプリを作っており、アプリ内で表示するダイアログの見た目をなるべく自作デザインで統一させようと思いました。
ダイアログの枠および背景と、下部の2つのボタン(YES/NO等)は共通にし、中身だけを生成する度に指定するようにして使い回しできないかと考えました。
そこで、まず BaseDialogFragment を用意し、枠とボタンのレイアウトを指定し、ここまではうまくいきました。
次に SingleKeyCoinNumDialogFragment を作り BaseDialogFragment を継承させ、onCreateView()をオーバーライドして親クラスで生成されたダイアログのレイアウトに中身のレイアウトをインフレートしようとしましたがうまくいきません…
親ダイアログクラスで設定したダイアログ枠の中に、子ダイアログクラスで生成したレイアウトが挿入されたものが返されてほしいのですが、return するものを変えてみてもどちらかしか表示されません。
以下コードです。
親ダイアログクラス
open class BaseDialogFragment : DialogFragment() {

    ～中略～

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {

        val dialog = Dialog(requireContext())
        // ダイアログの背景を透明にする(デフォルトの背景ではなく自作背景を表示するため)
        dialog.window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))

        // **元レイアウトはデータバインディングで指定**
        val binding = DialogBaseBinding.inflate(requireActivity().layoutInflater)

        binding.positiveButton.setOnClickListener {
            setFragmentResult(
                "RequestPositiveButtonKey",
                bundleOf()
            )
            dismiss()
        }
        binding.negativeButton.setOnClickListener {
            setFragmentResult(
                "RequestNegativeButtonKey",
                bundleOf()
            )
            dismiss()
        }

        dialog.setContentView(binding.root)

        return dialog
    }

    ～中略～

}

元レイアウト
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>

        <import type="android.view.View" />

        <import type="com.******.data.entity.Entry.Formula" />

        <import type="com.******.util.BindingUtils" />

        <variable
            name="viewmodel"
            type="com.******.addeditentry.AddEditEntryViewModel" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_dialog"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/dialog_padding_horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/dialog_padding_top"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dialog_padding_bottom">


        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp">

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/negative_button"
                style="@style/ControlButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="@{() -> viewmodel.cancel()}"
                android:text="キャンセル" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/positive_button"
                style="@style/PositiveButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height_regular"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="@{() -> viewmodel.saveEntry()}"
                android:text="完了" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</layout>

子ダイアログクラス
class SingleKeyCoinNumDialogFragment : BaseDialogFragment() {

    private var coinNum: Int = 0

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        // 親クラスで枠とボタンのみレイアウトした view を受け取る(元レイアウト)
        val view =  super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)

        // **元レイアウトの中の ConstraintLayout にインフレートしたい...**
        val contentFrame = view?.findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.content_frame)
        val content = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_content_single_key_coin_num, contentFrame, false)

        if (view != null) {
            dialog?.setContentView(view)
        }

        // Bundleに渡した値を取り出す
        arguments?.let {
            coinNum = it.getInt("NumKey", 0)
        }

        return view // 親クラスで作った枠とボタンしか表示されない

        // return content 子クラスで作った中身のレイアウトしか表示されない
    }

    ～中略～

}

インフレートしたいレイアウト
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/baseline_key_24" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView38"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="あいうえおかきくけこ"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Title" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/coins_row_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView47"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="合計"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Medium" />

            <com.snapps.swapp.view.CoinNumInputBox
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView48"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="枚"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Medium" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


以下のように修正して期待通りに表示できました。
親クラスの onCreateView() で枠とボタンのレイアウトを設定して返し、子クラスで受け取った View に対してインフレートすれば良いようです。
open class BaseDialogFragment : DialogFragment() {

    // ～中略～

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {

        val dialog = Dialog(requireContext())
        // ダイアログの背景を透明にする(デフォルトの背景ではなく自作背景を表示するため)
        dialog.window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))

        return dialog
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // カスタムダイアログのレイアウトファイルは dialog_base.xml
        val binding = DialogBaseBinding.inflate(requireActivity().layoutInflater, container, true)

        binding.positiveButton.setOnClickListener {
            setFragmentResult(
                "RequestPositiveButtonKey",
                bundleOf()
            )
            dismiss()
        }
        binding.negativeButton.setOnClickListener {
            setFragmentResult(
                "RequestNegativeButtonKey",
                bundleOf()
            )
            dismiss()
        }

        return binding.root
    }

    // ～中略～
   
}


class SingleKeyCoinNumDialogFragment : BaseDialogFragment() {

    private var coinNum: Int = 0

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        // 親クラスから受け取ったレイアウト済み View
        val view =  super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)

        val contentFrame = view?.findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.content_frame)
        val content = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_content_single_key_coin_num, contentFrame, true)

        // Bundleに渡した値を取り出す
        arguments?.let {
            coinNum = it.getInt("NumKey", 0)
        }

        contentFrame?.updateLayoutParams {
            width = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.dialog_content_width_1)
        }

        return view
    }

   // ～中略～

}


